Failed while parsing XML file ProjectSettings/GvhProjectSettings.xml
I get this error in Unity quite often. I have tried to solve it but not succeed.
Anyone that have any idea how to solve this problem.
So far I have tried:

Check the XML File for Formatting Issues
Look at Line 4, Position 19 - had not found a problem
Validate the XML with online tool
Check for Hidden Characters
Re-save the File with Correct Encoding

The xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<projectSettings>
    <projectSetting name="Google.IOSResolver.VerboseLoggingEnabled" value="False" />
    <projectSetting name="Google.PackageManagerResolver.VerboseLoggingEnabled"     value="False" />
    <projectSetting name="Google.VersionHandler.VerboseLoggingEnabled" value="False" />
</projectSettings>

Error message:
Failed while parsing XML file ProjectSettings/GvhProjectSettings.xml
System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 4, position 19.
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw (System.Exception e) [0x00027] in     <197f0c98606b4ba99b5865dfc26e5384>:0 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw (System.String res, System.String arg)     [0x00029] in <197f0c98606b4ba99b5865dfc26e5384>:0 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw (System.String res) [0x00000] in     <197f0c98606b4ba99b5865dfc26e5384>:0 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace () [0x0012c] in     <197f0c98606b4ba99b5865dfc26e5384>:0 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent () [0x002d4] in     <197f0c98606b4ba99b5865dfc26e5384>:0 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read () [0x0008c] in     <197f0c98606b4ba99b5865dfc26e5384>:0 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in <197f0c98606b4ba99b5865dfc26e5384>:0 
at Google.XmlUtilities+Reader.Read () [0x00018] in /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/XmlUtilities.cs:82 
at Google.XmlUtilities.ParseXmlTextFileElements (System.String filename, Google.Logger logger, Google.XmlUtilities+ParseElement parseElement) [0x00132] in /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/XmlUtilities.cs:145 

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Google.Logger:Log (string,Google.LogLevel) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/Logger.cs:136)
Google.XmlUtilities:ParseXmlTextFileElements (string,Google.Logger,Google.XmlUtilities/ParseElement) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/XmlUtilities.cs:149)
Google.ProjectSettings:Load () (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/ProjectSettings.cs:776)
Google.ProjectSettings:LoadIfEmpty () (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/ProjectSettings.cs:557)
Google.ProjectSettings:GetBool (string,bool,Google.SettingsLocation) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/ProjectSettings.cs:605)
Google.ProjectSettings:GetBool (string,bool) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/ProjectSettings.cs:618)
Google.IOSResolver:get_VerboseLoggingEnabled () (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/IOSResolver/src/IOSResolver.cs:984)
Google.IOSResolver:.cctor () (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/IOSResolver/src/IOSResolver.cs:689)
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes (System.Type[]) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/EditorAssemblies.cs:119)


You can read the xml like this:
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(path);
XmlNodeList projList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("projectSetting");
foreach (XmlNode node in projList)
{
    string name = node.Attributes["name"].Value;
    bool value = node.Attributes["value"].Value.Equals("True");
    ProjectSetting ps = new ProjectSetting(name, value);

    //Do anything you want to ps -> ProjectSetting
}

with the help of this class:
public class ProjectSetting
{
    public string name;
    public bool value;

    public ProjectSetting(string name, bool value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

